# selenium find_element_by_xpath text() not getting result

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

hi tried to get a text from the page but unable to get with selenium here is my code and i want copy onlty text from web page  my other xath element working just this getting error please help me to solve this one here is screen shot https://prnt.sc/qymf1s

```
    from selenium import webdriver 
    from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
    import urllib.request
    import mysql.connector
    import sys, os
    import requests
    css_album    = '/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/article/div/div/div[2]/p/text()[1]'
    driver = 0 

    def openbrowser():
    global driver
    xoptions = Options()
    #xoptions.add_argument("--headless") # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
    xoptions.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
    xoptions.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # applicable to windows os only
    xoptions.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches",["ignore-certificate-errors"])
    xoptions.add_argument('disable-infobars')
    xoptions.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    try:
      driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=xoptions)
      driver.set_window_size(55, 55)
    except:
      try:
        driver.close()
      except:
        print('Error in opening chrome')

      if len (sys.argv) <= 1:
    print('Please provide a URL')
    sys.exit()



     openbrowser()
       userurl = sys.argv[1]
       driver.get(userurl)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50000)
album = '';
try:
   album = driver.find_element_by_xpath(css_album).text
   print('Album:', album);
except:
   print('Error in album')
driver.close()
```

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?  Can you give the html or a link to the page?  These would give us what we need to help you better.

Comment: https://www.lyricsbell.com/sheikh-karan-aujla/ hi here is the page link empty result

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to access the element you are trying to retrieve the text with the xpath you are using.  I was able to get it with this xpath:

```
/html//div[@id='content']/article//div[@class='width:100%;position:relative']/div[2]/p
```

One issue though is that the 4 lines of text are all within this one element, so if you get the text you will get it all.  This is what the html looks like for this:

```
<p style="">Song – Sheikh<br>
Singers – Karan Aujla<br>
Musicians – Deep Jandu<br>
Lyricists – Karan Aujla
</p>
```

You can get the text and then take the substring of the song text that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following xpath :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='top_ad']//following-sibling::p")).getText()
```

This will return you:

```
Song – Sheikh
Singers – Karan Aujla
Musicians – Deep Jandu
Lyricists – Karan Aujla
```

Hope this helps.